# @DeleteMapping spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

why is the DELETE query not working for me.

```
    @DeleteMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("userId") long id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

There is a form for this mapping, but it returns me the Request method 'GET' is not supported.

```
<form th:object="${users}">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="window.location.href = 'add'"/>
        <input th:formaction="@{/update}" type="submit" value="Update" th:method="patch" class="button"/>
        <input th:formaction="@{/delete}" type="submit" value="Delete" th:method="delete"/>
    <select th:name="userId">
        <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${user.surname}"></td>
                <td th:text="${user.age}"></td>
            </tr>
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

If I do @GetMapping, then everything works, but I understand that this is not correct, the delete request is not executed in this case.

If I do this, then delete works, but PATCH does not work.

```
<form th:object="${users}" th:method="delete">
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="window.location.href = 'add'"/>
    <input th:formaction="@{/update}" type="submit" value="Update" th:method="patch" class="button"/>
    <input th:formaction="@{/delete}" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
<select th:name="userId">
    <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${user.surname}"></td>
            <td th:text="${user.age}"></td>
        </tr>
    </option>
</select>
```

how to make userId available in an external form, that is, outside the loop

I have redone the task, these forms work separately. How do I make this select look at two forms.

```
<select th:name="userId" id="userid" th:form="form_update | form_delete" >
<option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}">
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${user.surname}"></td>
        <td th:text="${user.age}"></td>
    </tr>
</option>
```

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="window.location.href = 'add'"/>

<form action="#" th:id="form_delete"  th:action="@{/delete}" th:object="${users}" th:method="delete">
<input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
```

```
<form action="#" th:id="form_update"  th:action="@{/update}" th:object="${users}" th:method="patch">
<input type="submit" value="Update"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `th:method="delete"` in the form?

Comment: yes, is that wrong? how can I do this, help me

Comment: Browsers [don't support the DELETE method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#method) in forms. If you want to use the DELETE method you'll need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

HTML forms support only `GET` and `POST` methods.

If you want to use a `DELETE` method, you will have to use JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not using html, I'm using thymeleaf

Comment: how to make userId available in an external form, that is, outside the loop

Comment: Thymeleaf is generating HTML code. It's best to look at what it has generated and go from there.

Comment: Šimon is correct. If you want to make a HTTP DELETE call, you'll need to use Javascript, since HTML forms only support GET and POST methods. Thymeleaf is just a template engine that spitts out the marker language you're using, in this case, HTML.